# What is the difference between l() and url()?

Tags: 7

Why does Drupal provide `l()` and `url()`, which seems to have the same purpose?

Answer (score 10):

[`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7.x) creates a clickable link (an HTML anchor tag), while [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7.x) creates just a url. If you scroll down in the `l()` page you'll see the following source code:

```
  if ($use_theme) {
    return theme('link', array('text' => $text, 'path' => $path, 'options' => $options));
  }
  // The result of url() is a plain-text URL. Because we are using it here
  // in an HTML argument context, we need to encode it properly.
  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($path, $options)) . '"' . drupal_attributes($options['attributes']) . '>' . ($options['html'] ? $text : check_plain($text)) . '</a>';
```

[`theme_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_link/7.x) has a similar construction. So `l()` is using `url()` to construct the anchor.

So summarizing, the one is for clickable links, the other for plain (unclickable) url's.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the documentation correctly, function `url($path = NULL, array $options = array())` returns a string, which is URL of given path.

Whereas function `l($text, $path, array $options = array())` has an advanced parameter `$text` and returns an html anchor with given text, given path and options.